# WPF XAML Trying to bind the Width of a DataGrid Column

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid, width

I'd like to bind the Width of my Columns to a Property in my Model so I can save it if the user resize it. I'd like a solution with no code behind.
This is what I have so far:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgArticles"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Specifications.Articles}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Number" Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Number}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Specifications.Config.NumberColumnWidth}" MinWidth="70" >
```

Model:

```
public class Specifications
{
    private ConfigurationGrid config
    public ConfigurationGrid Config { get { return config; } set { } }

    private ObservableCollection<Article> articles;
    public ObservableCollection<Article> Articles
    {
        get { return articles; }
        set { }
    }


public class ConfigurationGrid : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double numberColumnWidth;
    public double NumberColumnWidth
    {
        get { return numberColumnWidth; }
        set { numberColumnWidth = value;  OnPropertyChanged("numberColumnWidth"); }
    }

    public ConfigurationGrid() { }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I managed to bind the Width of a sub Datagrid Column which is in my RowDetailsTemplate to the Width of another column like so:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" CellStyle="{StaticResource QuantityStyle}" Binding="{Binding Quantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=\{0:n\}}" 
                                                    Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Mesure}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
```

This works fine but I don't know why it's not working on my main DataGrid.
After debugging I noticed that it doesn't even reach the Getter of NumberColumnWidth.
Does anyone know a way to make it work? Thank you

## **Edit**

I tried the solution provided by @mm8 but it didn't work. It's still not reaching the Getter. Maybe I missed something. Here is what the code looks like right now:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CachView.Views.GridView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CachView.ViewModels"
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:CachView.Converters"
         xmlns:util="clr-namespace:CachView.Util"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ArticleViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid Margin="10">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgArticles"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Specifications.Articles}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <util:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Number" Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Number}" Width="{Binding Data.Specifications.Config.NumberColumnWidth, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
                                MinWidth="70">

            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class GridView : UserControl
{
    public GridView(ArticleViewModel a)
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = a;
    }   
}
```

And my BindingProxy class is the same as in the example:

```
    class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

My project is a UserControl that is meant to be used from a WinForm application. Here is how it is implemented and how I set the DataContext and properties. It is done from the Controller of my WinForm application.

```
class Controller
{

    private ArticleViewModel articleViewModel;
    private ElementHost elementHost;
    private MainWindow winformView;
    public ArticleViewModel ArticleViewModel { get { return articleViewModel; } }
    public Collection<Article> Articles { get; set; } 
    public Specifications Specs { get; set; }       

    public Controleur(MainWindow view) // The view is received from Program.cs
    {
        this.winformView = view;
        Articles = new Collection<Article>();
        populateArticles(); // This create hard coded articles for testing purpose

        ConfigurationGrid config= new ConfigurationGrid();
        config.NumberColumnWidth = 300;

        Specs = new Specifications(Articles);
        Specs.Config = config;

        articleViewModel = new ArticleViewModel(Specs);


        GridView gridView = new GridView(articleViewModel); //This is my WPF UserControl

        elementHost = new ElementHost();
        elementHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.winformView.Controls.Add(elementHost);
        elementHost.Child = gridView;           
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class ArticleViewModel 
{
    private Specifications specifications;
    public Specifications Specifications { get { return specifications; } set { } }



    public ArticleViewModel() { }

    public ArticleViewModel(Specifications c)
    {
        this.specifications = c;
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataGridTextColumn` is not a visual element that gets added to the element tree so you won't be able to bind to a `RelativeSource` since there are no ancestors to bind to.

If you want to be able to bind the `Width` property to a view model property you could use a `BindingProxy` object that captures the `DataContext` as suggested in the following blog post.

**[WPF] How to bind to data when the DataContext is not inherited:** https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Comment: I tested this solution but it's not working. I can't get the Width to bind to the property. Once again the getter is not reached.

Comment: Apparently you did something wrong then. Make sure that you bind the Data property of the BindingProxy to your view model and post your code if you want anyone to be able to point out where your mistake is.

Comment: You forgot to include code that demonstrates how you set up the DataContext, how you set the NumberColumnWidth etc. You should provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example when you ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm prety new to Stack Overflow. I added the code you requested. I hope this helps find a solution. Tell me if I forgot other informations and thank you for your time.